# installing svgcairo package in ubuntu

Tags: linux, configuration, ubuntu-14.04, cabal, cairo

I want to install "svgcairo" package on my ubuntu14.04 OS by the command `cabal install svgcairo` but it fails, and give me the following error message: 
`Resolving dependencies...
[1 of 2] Compiling SetupWrapper     ( /tmp/svgcairo-0.13.0.1-4392/svgcairo-0.13.0.1/SetupWrapper.hs, /tmp/svgcairo-0.13.0.1-4392/svgcairo-0.13.0.1/dist/setup/SetupWrapper.o )`

``` /tmp/svgcairo-0.13.0.1-4392/svgcairo-0.13.0.1/SetupWrapper.hs:12:39:
    Module
    ``Distribution.Simple.Configure'
    does not export ```
 `configCompilerEx`
`Failed to install svgcairo-0.13.0.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
svgcairo-0.13.0.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1`


Anyone have an idea?

Comment: What version of ghc?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce with:
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS , Ghc 7.6.3, and cabal-install version 1.22.0.1
using version 1.22.1.1 of the Cabal library.

Comment: Are my versions above the same as yours?